# auth.provider is not set to 'password' when user signs-in with email and password

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am developing an iOS app using Firebase (the newest) and I am having trouble with the `auth.provider` expression in the security rules when the user is authenticated using an email and password. I expect the `auth.provider` expression to return `password` but instead it looks like it returns `anonymous`.

In the Firebase console, I have enabled Email/Password and Google as providers, and have set up the following security rules:

```json
    {
      "rules": {
          "users": {
            "$uid": {

            // the user is allowed to read
            ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",

            // the non-anonymous user is allowed to write
            ".write": "auth.uid === $uid && auth.provider !== 'anonymous'"
            
            // more here, omitted for brevity
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

In my app, when signing in as a user XYZ with an e-mail and password, I am not able to set a value under the /users/XYZ node. I am getting a "permission denied" error. This is not the case with users signing-in with Google credentials, where it works as expected.

It looks like the culprit is the condition `auth.provider !== 'anonymous'`. For an e-mail/password sign-in, I expect the provider to be equal to `password`; instead it appears to be set to `anonymous`. The Firebase documentation lists "password" as a possible value for auth.provider: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#auth

This issue has bigger ramifications, when one enables the new "anonymous authentication" feature (see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth). As I understand it, using `auth.provider` in the security rules would allow one to distinguish between an "anonymous" user and a "password" user.

Am I looking at a bug or am I making a beginner's mistake somewhere in my reasoning?

For reference, here are the SDK versions I am using (excerpt from CocoaPods output):

```
Using Firebase (3.2.1)
Using FirebaseAuth (3.0.2)
Using FirebaseDatabase (3.0.1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase team confirmed that there is a bug somewhere on their side and are working for a fix. In the meantime, there is a workaround to be found in the link below:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/firebase-talk/C-ljg-CCKl0/discussion

The workaround consists of using the following security rule for detecting that the user authenticated using an e-mail address:

```
auth.token.firebase.identities.email !== null
```

Answer (score 0):

Not being very helpful, but I wanted to say I have the same issue using the Javascript client API. I've sent a support question to the Firebase team. If I get any updates I'll post them here.