# Firebase auth rules working for facebook provider but not email/pwd

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I am trying to write some rules on my DB that prevent the user from writing unless they are authenticated with a provider other than 'anonymous'. This is the rule that I have but for some reason it works when im logged in with facebook but not with email/password; I get a permission denied error. PS the email/pwd user was created before the upgraded SDK. Any thoughts why this is not working?

```
  "updates": {
    ".read": "auth !== null",
    ".write": "auth !== null && auth.provider !== 'anonymous'",
    "$location_id": {
      ".indexOn": "validFrom",
      "$update_id": {
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['displayName', 'place_id', 'name', 'statusValueId', 'update_id', 'user_id', 'validFrom', 'votes'])"
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to check why this is not working is using the simulator in the firebase console.

You can find it in Database>Rules>Simulator (top-right corner)

[image]

1. Select Write in the radio button
2. Select the toggle "Authenticated", select the provider you want to test and write in "Auth token payload" your user's token
3. Write in "Location" the path to your reference
4. Paste in "Data (JSON)" the JSON object you want to write
5. Click run and firebase will tell you which rule fails

Comment: ☃ And if this doesn't completely answer the question, then include the output from the simulator to help diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are hitting the same bug as me, where `auth.provider` is equal to `anonymous` for email/password authentication instead of `password`. Sadly, I haven't yet received an answer from the Firebase team.

[auth.provider is not set to 'password' when user signs-in with email and password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37624131/6421304)

Update: I received some great help in the Google groups page of Firebase. They confirmed the bug and provided a workaround. See the link below:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/firebase-talk/C-ljg-CCKl0/discussion

Comment: I believe we indeed have the exact same issue