# Firebase Permission denied (read and write) with Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I want to read and write in my database with authentication but I got a `Permission denied` for both. I'm trying to figure out why it's not working.

I used the default rules since I want authentication, as explained in the doc.

> The default rules require Authentication. They allow full read and write > access to authenticated users of your app. They are useful if you want data open > to all users of your app but don't want it open to the world.

- **Firebase rules :**

  ```
  {
    "rules": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
  ```
- **Create user :**

  ```
     auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                  Log.d("USER_CREATE", "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                  // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                  // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                  // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                  if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed.",
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  } else {
                      startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                      finish();
                  }

                  // ...
              }
          });
  ```
- **Sign in user :**

  ```
  auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                  Log.d("COMPLETE", "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
              }
          });
  ```

I got an `AuthListener`and it logs me that the user is signed in.

- **AuthListener :**

  ```
  mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
          @Override
          public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
              FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
              if (user != null) {
                  // User is signed in
                  Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
              } else {
                  // User is signed out
                  Log.d("TAG", "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
              }
              // ...
          }
      };
      // ...
  ```
- **Read test :** (with a node I manually added in the database)

  ```
  firebase.child("test").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
          Log.d("result", snapshot.getValue()+"");
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(FirebaseError error) {
          Log.d("The read failed: ", error.getMessage());
      }
  });
  ```
- **Write test** : I want a main node `users`with two categories of users : `devs`and `employers`.

  ```
  Firebase usersRef  = firebase.child("users").child("devs");
      FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

  Map<String, String> userMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
  userMap.put("name", "blabla");
  userMap.put("city", "Brussels");

  Map<String, Map<String, String>> users = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
  users.put(user.getUid().toString(), userMap);
  usersRef.setValue(users);
  ```
- **Logs :**

  ```
  D/AUTH LISTENER: onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:wnomkwiOWOb4wNNLSsrWeT5xxUq1
  D/USER_CREATE: createUserWithEmail:onComplete:true
  I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
  D/ACTION BAR?: android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar@36c3cd2a
  W/SyncTree: Listen at /test failed: FirebaseError: Permission denied
  D/The read failed:: Permission denied
  D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying listeners about user ( wnomkwiOWOb4wNNLSsrWeT5xxUq1 ).
  D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying listeners about user ( wnomkwiOWOb4wNNLSsrWeT5xxUq1 ).
  D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
  D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.
  D/AUTH LISTENER: onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:wnomkwiOWOb4wNNLSsrWeT5xxUq1
  D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
  D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.
  D/AUTH LISTENER: onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:wnomkwiOWOb4wNNLSsrWeT5xxUq1
  D/COMPLETE: signInWithEmail:onComplete:true
  ```

I made those 2 tests with public permission (write : true, read : true) and it was working, so something must be wrong with my authentication. I'm probably misunderstanding/missing something but don't really see what exactly. Would be very nice If someone would like to enlighten me!

Comment: can you share the screenshot for registered user and permission tab in Firebase console?

Comment: Have you tested your rules in the [simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37911209/4695325)? If you need further help you can post the result here.

Also, from your log seems that you are calling `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` and `signInWithEmailAndPassword` every time your app starts. You should use `onAuthStateChanged` to detect if the user is already logged in. You should use `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` if he needs to create an "account" or `signInWithEmailAndPassword` if he is already registered and he wants to log in

Comment: @DevidFarinelli I just tested the rules with the simulator, using a 'Custom' authentication (since in my app I'm using email/password authentication) and it works fine for both, so I assume the problem stands in my authentication process. The code comes from the SignupActivity, so that's why I'm creating and signing users every time.

Comment: @LalitPoptani here are the screenshots of some Firebase console tabs, let me know if you need more infos! http://imgur.com/a/lIxuH

Comment: @DevidFarinelli my idea was to add the user in the database after its authentication, I'd be able to get the uid and then store it in my database, under 'users/devs/' or 'users/employees', with the uid as key then different properties (name, location, etc), does it sounds right to you?

Comment: It depends on how do you want to retrieve them, but generally it sounds like a good solution ;)

Comment: @DevidFarinelli yes, except I got that 'Permission denied' problem. How is it possible? It seems my user is authenticated, so I should be able to write and read...

Comment: The only things that come to my mind are:
1) you are not correctly authenticated when querying firebase (have you tried keeping only `onAuthStateChanged`?)
2) you are not using the simulator correctly (have you pasted your JSON auth token in the "Auth token payload" section of the simulator using custom provider?)

PS: I missed your replied to my answer in your other question. I'm gonna take a look there as soon as I can. I'm a little bit busy. ;)

Comment: @DevidFarinelli Don't worry, I'm working on others parts of the app so for now, I put the read/write permissions as "true". Something probably wrong with my authentication flow indeed, but don't really understand what. My code is on github btw, if you want to look at it : https://github.com/raphh11/MyApp. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing the old Firebase SDK with the new Firebase SDK. Remove firebase-android-sdk 2.5.2 from your build.gradle and update your imports to use the new `DatabaseReference` class instead of the `Firebase` class.

Answer (score 0):

I am using com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.5.0. I have set following rules in firebase.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Still I am getting

> PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Authentication failed: permission_denied
>   (Access denied.).